# Push each API element on the list

Tags: javascript, list, api, for-loop, error-handling

Im trying to pushing each API response on my list :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFvoi.png)

but unfortunately i got this error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brMCp.png)

```
async loadCards() {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get("https://api.adzuna.com/...");
    var list = [];
    response.data.results.forEach(elem => {
      elem.push(list)
      console.log(list)
    });     
  } 
  catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
      }
},
```

Comment: Please use code blocks to include error messages instead of images in the future.

Comment: @Moritz-Mahringer no problem

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to loop through the response and for each result, you wanna enter to the list, right? if so update the code with following

```
async loadCards() {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get("https://api.adzuna.com/...");
    var list = [];
    response.data.results.forEach(elem => {
      list.push(elem)
      console.log(list)
    });     
  } 
  catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
      }
},
```

Because you wanna push elements to the list you initialized
a simple example is

```
 const array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var newarray = []
array1.forEach(element => {
newarray.push(element)});
```

Here we are taking elements from array1 and pushing them to the new array. Hope it makes sense now

Answering to your comment as you wanna enter the full response and not each element sepeartely you could use this following

```
async loadCards() {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get("https://api.adzuna.com/...");
        var list = [];
        response.data.forEach(elem => {
          list.push(elem)
          console.log(list)
        });     
      } 
      catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
          }
    },
```

Comment: thanks i resolve that but now the `.foreach` looping on him so i got 9 time the same request rather than all element present on the object i wanted

Comment: So if you wanna add each response from api to the list you probably just have to loop through response.data not throgh response.data.results

Comment: i have added the new code as an edit to the answer

Comment: it didnt work, i got the same first error with `TypeError`

Comment: can you please add a detailed error message!

Comment: i put a update now

Answer (score 0):

So you could try

```
    `async loadCards() {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get("https://api.adzuna.com/...");
var string1 = JSON.stringify(response.data);

var parsed = JSON.parse(string1);  
        data = JSON.parse(response.data);
        var list = [];
        parsed.forEach(elem => {
          list.push(elem)
          console.log(list)
        });     
        
      
      } 
      catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
          }
    },`
```

Comment: i got SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at _callee$ (index.js?a47b:16:1)
    at tryCatch (runtime.js?96cf:63:1)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (runtime.js?96cf:294:1)
    at Generator.eval [as next] (runtime.js?96cf:119:1)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (asyncToGenerator.js?1da1:3:1)
    at _next (asyncToGenerator.js?1da1:25:1)

Comment: Or maybe with this ?? `const { data } = response;`

Comment: I have added the code to stringify the output from API and then parsed it. Hopefully it fixes your issue@Cml_93